# Segueing to New View Controller while Dismissing previous without navigation controller: swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, dismiss, unwind-segue

Hello I am pretty annoyed with this:

Originally, I had many segues in my storyboard. Each button at bottom of tool bar would segue to various view controllers. As you can imagine, that is a lot of segues for 6 different items on toolbar. After segueing, each action would call self.dismiss and everything would be ok.

Recently, I wanted to clean up the storyboard.

I created the function:

```
 extension UIViewController {

    func segue(StoryboardID: String) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: 
    nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: StoryboardID)
    popOverVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
    popOverVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    print("dismissed")
    self.present(popOverVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    print("presented")
  }
```

}

What I am seeing is that the dismiss dismisses the new view controller from appearing. It essentially goes back to my first view controller presented upon launch. I want to dismiss all view controllers so that I don't keep piling up my views.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a `UITabBarController` or build your own equivalent using a container view controller?

Comment: Thank you we will end up doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you present your `popOverVC` from a view controller that is being dismissed, so your `popOverVC` will never be shown as its parent is being dismissed.

Not sure how your architecture is exactly but you would either need to use the `delegate` pattern to tell the parent when to segue, for example:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.delegate?.didDismiss(viewController: self)
}
```

Or to use some trick to get the top most view controller to present your `popOverVC` after the current view has been dismissed, ex:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter{$0.isKeyWindow}.first!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    topController.present(popOverVC, animated: true)
}
```

But I agree with @Paulw11, a UITabBarController seem like a much better option for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you yes we ended up converting to TabBarController